# Can ApplicationState Expire like SessionState in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a timeout for Session object of HttpSessionState that can be set. I want to see if we can make HttpApplicationState timeout too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx), this can be achieved very easy.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make it expire this way.

Why? Because it is supposed to be valid so long as the application is running.

If you want to make an application state value that will expire, you can implement such a function yourself, using one of the timer classes.

Comment: The real answer to my question is yours, but the solution to my answer is GvS's answer